# ¿Cómo hacer split por pipe en java?

Tags: java, regex

Tengo las​ siguientes​ líneas​:

```
valor1=cadena.split("|")[0];
valor2=cadena.split("|")[1] ;
```

Sin embargo, estoy obteniendo `null`, lo que quiere decir que no estoy obteniendo ningún valor al hacer el split.

He intentado lo mismo pero con **coma**:

```
valor1=cadena.split(",")[0];
valor2=cadena.split(",")[1] ;
```

Y esto sí funciona.

Comment: Split [nunca](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902078/is-it-possible-that-java-string-split-can-return-a-null-string#6902125) retorna `null`. Si no hay coincidencias, retorna la misma cadena de entrada.

Comment: @Alfabravo Eso no lo sabía, gracias por aclarar eso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hola amigo te recomiendo que hagas esto:

Para hacer un split en java usando como patrón de separación un carácter especial ".", "$", etc…  Debemos utilizar los carácteres de escape "\" como prefijo.

Codigo:

```
String[] palabras = cadena.split("\\.");
```

En tu caso seria algo como esto:

```
 valor1=cadena.split("\\|")[0];

valor2=cadena.split("\\|")[1] ;
```

En este link te ayudara tambien:

[Metodo Split en Java](http://muchocodigo.com/metodo-split-en-java/)

Answer (score 5):

Debido a que el método [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) de la clase [`java.lang.String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) recibe, en primer lugar, una expresión regular, el carácter `|` (sin escapar) es considerado como *operador de alternancia*.<sup>1</sup>

❍ Sin escape

```
"a|b||d".split("|") ⇒ ["a", "|", "b", "|", "|", "d", ""]
```

❍ Con escape

De ahí que sea necesario escapar el `|` con `\`. Es decir:

```
"a|b||d".split("\\|") ⇒ ["a", "b", "", "d"]
```

❍ Sin límite

No obstante, quizás sea más conveniente especificar el límite. Por ejemplo, sin límite especificado:

```
"a|||".split("\\|") ⇒ ["a"]
```

❍ Con límite (`-1`)

```
"a|||".split("\\|", -1) ⇒ ["a", "", "", ""]
```

---

*Notas*

1. [Alternation with The Vertical Bar or Pipe Symbol](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (*en inglés*).

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que usar

```
valor1=cadena.split("\\|")[0];
```

El método `split(String regex)` usa una expresión regular, entonces tienes que escapar el `|`, o separas por "nada o nada".

Answer (score 2):

Se puede almacenar en un array los elementos separados por el pipe `|` mediante **.split("\\|")**:

```
String cadena = "Mike|Irina|John|Mary|Joseph";
String[] valores = cadena.split("\\|");
```

o mediante **.split(Pattern.quote("|"))** :

```
  String[] valores = cadena.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

para obtener sus valores

```
String valor1 = valores[0];  //valor Mike 
String valor2 = valores[1];  //valor Irina
String valor3 = valores[2];  //valor John
String valor4 = valores[3];  //valor Mary
String valor5 = valores[4];  //valor Joseph
```

---

También puedes obtener directamente los valores de la cadena de esta forma:

```
String valor1 = cadena.split("\\|")[0]; //valor Mike 
String valor2 = cadena.split("\\|")[1];  //valor Irina
String valor3 = cadena.split("\\|")[2];  //valor John
...
```

o mediante **`.split(Pattern.quote("|"))`** :

```
 String valor1 = cadena.split(Pattern.quote("|"))[0]; //valor Mike 
 String valor2 = cadena.split(Pattern.quote("|"))[1];  //valor Irina
 String valor3 = cadena.split(Pattern.quote("|"))[2];  //valor John
 ...
 ...
```

---

A diferencia de :

```
 String[] valores = cadena.split(",");
```

que se puede realizar sin realizar escape del caracter `","` ya que no es un caracter especial.

Comment: Esta es la respuesta que responde al caso genérico y lo que se debería usar como buena práctica. `Pattern.quote()` es sin duda la opción a usar.

Answer (score 2):

Yo te recomendaría remplazar tu "\" por "," con el método replace java.lang.String, quédandote algo como esto:

```
String cadenaN = cadena.replace("\\\",",");
valor1=cadenaN.split(",")[0];
valor2=cadenaN.split(",")[1];
```

O hacerle cómo indican arriba.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración